# Border radius is hidden by :after

Tags: html, css

I need to add a `border-radius` like in the following picture:
[image]

But if i try to add a border-radius in the bottom right corner it gets hidden by the `:after` that creates the triangle in the bottom left corner.

How can i solve this?

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a img {
  display: block;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-61deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/beautiful-tree-middle-field-covered-with-grass-with-tree-line-background_181624-29267.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

My link to codepen  https://codepen.io/vetal81/pen/NWjqGgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `:before` and a radial gradient as background:

```css
a:before {
    ...
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 30px, white 30px);
}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a img {
  display: block;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-61deg);
  border-radius: 0 30px 0 0;
}

a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 30px, white 30px);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/beautiful-tree-middle-field-covered-with-grass-with-tree-line-background_181624-29267.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to it /. It is hard to give. This is my profession. But after a stroke, the arm and leg do not work well. At the age of 40 I had to learn a new one.))))))))) Thank you very much.

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).